# Manhwa about priestess who destroyed her own village reincarnated as cursed unlucky girl

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

Manhwa about a female lead who is extremely unlucky and can see spirits. Later revealed to be a reincarnation of a powerful priestess who broke her vows and destroyed her village and was cursed to be unlucky. Befriends owner of a shop which also houses other magical misfits including a vampire from England who likes to bake. Owner of the shop is also sensitive to impurities like blood and guarding a portal between realms and has a right hand man who is later revealed to be a reincarnation of her lover in that past life.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: Hi Logic, I can't remember the colour of FL hair but I don't think it was pivotal to the story.

Comment: Knowing the hair colour of the main character/s helps to rule stuff out more quickly when looking through images.

Comment: It might have just been black, I think the manhwa was black and white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely *[Dokebi Cafe](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/dokebi-cafe)*.

> Dokebi Cafe: Sacred Grounds for Those Who Wait" I will only love you even if I were to be born a thousand times." **Gangeun is a poster girl for bad luck**. She's a magnet for accidents small and large. Just when she's getting used to her eventful high school life, she encounters a strange "boy" named Mooyoung in front of a new cafe. What is this curious place? Who is this mysterious creature in the form of a boy? Bad luck seems to have left Gangeun but there's so much more that awaits her.

The story opens with Gangeun dreaming of the past, followed by multiple incidents of extremely bad luck. She sees a new cafe on her way to school and a young boy waiting outside it, briefly with visible fox ears. When she talks to him later, he states that she shouldn't be able to see her - this is likely the "sees spirits" from the question, but there's no indication she was able to do this prior to meeting him.

[image: Main character encounters fox boy]

From talking to him, he states that this cafe is a place of meeting; she either wants to meet someone, or someone wants to meet her. The implication being that she wants to meet someone from her past life from the dream. There's a hint that the person she's to meet is at the cafe as the owner's "mercenary", but this isn't confirmed as of the chapters I've read.

Similarly, her exact circumstances in her past life haven't been confirmed, but the owner does refer to her as the shaman of a ruined kingdom.

[image: Hint to the main character's past]

I also haven't seen the vampire or any real details about the owner, but there's enough similarities that I'm confident that this is the manhwa.

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `Curse/s` and `Unlucky Protagonist`.

Comment: Thank you! This is the manhwa I was looking for!

Comment: @Victoria You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).